# electrical fault suzuki sv650s 2000

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, suzuki, sv650

We have a Suzuki sv650s 2000. It was working when bought but now nothing from starter switch. tested the wiring and it's live upto the box under seat then nothing ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you please edit your post and tell us *what box under the seat* you're talking about? As it stands, the question is way too broad, meaning it could be just about anything.

Comment: @paulster2 I think she is talking about the fuse box. Linda are you sure you have enough power in the battery? Also, can you try to start the bike on neutral? If it starts on neutral then one of the safety features on the bike failed.